# Is there a synonym for "flunky" that specifically denotes a failed student at university?

Tags: synonyms

Am searching for a term to denote a person who has failed within a university, ie. someone who could not excel in his or her course of study. Not a dropout, per se, or someone who simply could not continue on in their studies, but someone who fails to understand the majority of their course work.

Comment: I **guess** that you get *flunky* from the verb *flunk* meaning to fail dismally, generally in exams. Why does the agent noun *flunker* not work?

Comment: Beware, the word "flunky" is not related to the verb "flunk" but to the verb "flank": to be on the side of something. Flunky was originally a (derogatory) term for a certain type of servant; nowadays it negatively refers to subordinates.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "flunkee" rather than "flunky"? (Not synonyms; different pronunciations.)

Comment: Am I to understand that the desired synonym should describe  someone who "fails to understand" and not someone who flunks for other reasons (such as attending parties and not going to class).

Comment: ‘Flunker’ sounds good to me.

Comment: "Am I to understand that the desired synonym should describe someone who "fails to understand" and not someone who flunks for other reasons (such as attending parties and not going to class). – GEdgar 22 hours ago
--Yes, precisely.

Comment: The word for a footman or servant is usually spelled _flunkey_. I can't think of a one-word term for what you describe; you could say something like "He was out of his depth at university".